# how can i define functions if it involve syntactically wrong word?

Tags: javascript

i was try to defined function like under code and conditions.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:pdfDownload('/pdf_name/spec_name.pdf'); return false;"><span class="icon-left"></a>

var onclickValue = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[41].getAttribute('onclick')
#above a tag is 41st.
```

but onclickValue is not define.

i think, it does not seem to be declared because of a string like ':'.

in this case how can i define onclick's value function?

Specifically, what I want is the spec_name of the tag and I want to declare it as a variable.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: When and where are you executing this code?

Comment: Now it runs in the Chrome console window, but it will run later on in Adobe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try checking if it's `undefined` or `null`? You may want to consider only getting the file names based on an identifier (unique `id` or CSS `class` name).
Ideally you would want to know which links would have PDF files though, probably adding a CSS `class`- something like `download-link` - since you would be reusing it multiple times:

`<a class="download-link" href="#" onclick="javascript:pdfDownload('/pdf_name/spec_name.pdf'); return false;"><span class="icon-left"></a>`

So that you can just select the elements specifically:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('download-link').forEach(getFileNames);

function getFileNames(item) {
    if (item && item.getAttributeNode("onclick").specified) {
        var fileName = item.getAttributeNode("onclick").split("/").pop();
        //do something with fileName
    }
}
```

Instead of using `getElementsByTagName()` which iterates over all `a` tags, but if for some reason you cannot modify the code, the code below maybe what you need:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a').forEach(getFileNames);
```

Comment: when i define onclick Value that above code, in console window it show me 'undefine' message.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByTagName('a')[41]` is not a good approach. What if the index changes?

As the project evolves, the elements' indices will definitely change. So it's much better to use a class or id as below:

```
<a id="downloadPDFLink" href="#"><span class="icon-left"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var downloadLink = getElementById("downloadPDFLink");

    downloadLink.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // do something here
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: I do not have the right to modify the code, and I do coding for tagging.

Comment: Then you can probably do something like: <a id="downloadPDFLink" href="#" onclick="pdfDownload('/pdf_name/spec_name.pdf'); return false;"><span class="icon-left"></a>